# Is the "ancestor" relationship impossible to define in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

*Definition:* Given a binary relationship $R$, an ancestor relationship $R^*$ exists between $a$ and $b$ iff there is a chain of relationships $R$ connecting $a$ and $b$, for example, $Rax$, $Rxy$ and $Ryb$.

$R^*$ is trivial to define in [logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming) (whose logical aspect is often said to be a subset of first-order logic). However, a paper I was reading claimed that $R^*$ cannot be defined in first-order logic. Is this true?

---

A [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) definition of `ancestor` given `parent`:

$$
\begin{align}
ancestor(X, Y) & \leftarrow parent(X, Y)
\\
ancestor(X, Y) & \leftarrow parent(X, Z) \land ancestor(Z, Y)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is that First-Order Logic uses Tarskian semantics and logic programming uses Herbrand semantics. This has various consequences when it comes to expressiveness and other properties like compactness and completeness. For more details, see for example [The Herbrand Manifesto](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/extras/manifesto.html) or [Herbrand Semantics](http://logic.stanford.edu/herbrand/herbrand.html), where your example (transitive closure) is discussed.

Comment: very useful insight. thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is a standard application of the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem).

Here's a rough idea. Consider a theory which says (and adopt a mild abuse of notation):

- $aR^*b$,
- There is no $c_1$ with $aRc_1Rb$,
- There are no $c_1,c_2$ with $aRc_1Rc_2Rb$,
- There are no $c_1,c_2,c_3$ with $aRc_1Rc_2Rc_3Rb$,
- etc.

This is obviously finitely consistent (just consider a "chain of length $n$" for $n$ large enough), but equally obviously unsatisfiable. So by compactness some clause must not actually be first-order expressible - and the only option is the first one.

---

EDIT: Re: the prolog definition you describe *(caution: I'm not familiar with prolog)*; at a quick glance "negation-as-failure" is a bit nuanced. I would start by observing that first-order logic does **not** allow recursive, or least-fixed-point, definitions; in particular, the transitive closure of a definable relation in a structure need not be definable in that same structure.

- Wait, but isn't Godel coding all about recursive definitions? Well, sort of - but there's some subtleties there. Godel shows that in *certain structures/theories* we can handle *certain recursive constructions* in a "reasonably decent" way. That's a far cry from what's wanted here.

As I said above, at a glance "negation-as-failure" has some subtlety to it (specifically, nonmonotonicity). However I do think that the above is really the heart of the issue, and will wind up being relevant to however one tries to link prolog and first-order logic.

Comment: So how come we can define it in prolog? Is this entirely due to negation-as-failure?

Comment: @MaxB I'm not familiar with prolog, so I couldn't answer that.

Comment: @MaxB I've added a bit about that. It's speculative since I'm not familiar with prolog, but it will hopefully be relevant.

Comment: You could translate those statements directly into FOL: `∀x ∀y (Parent(x, y) ∨ (∃z Parent(x, z) ∧ Ancestor(z, y)) ⇔ Ancestor(x, y))` but I believe the meaning is different due to no negation-as-failure.

Comment: I don't think any of the literature I read about FOL included the concept of a "definition", just "statements".

Comment: @MaxB (Are you familiar with the term "expansion by definitions?") Let me rephrase. The sentence you've written down does **not** in fact "pin down" the Ancestor relation, relative to the Parent relation, in any sense. For example, suppose we have a relation Parent on a given set such that each thing is the Parent of at least one thing. Then if we interpret "Ancestor" as the *total* relation on our set (everything is related to everything else), we get something satisfying the sentence you've written.

Comment: It may help to think semantically. Suppose I have a binary relation $R$ on a set $X$ (so a directed graph), and I ask whether the transitive closure $R^*$ of $R$ is a first-order-definable relation on the structure $(X;R)$. It is true that $R^*$ satisfies a particular property, namely it is one of the relations $S$ with the property that $$\forall x,y\in X(xSy\leftrightarrow (xRy\vee \exists z(xRz\wedge zSy))).$$ However, this falls well short of a definition in any sense.